# Protobuf-net enum backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, enums, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, backwards-compatibility

I was trying to add a new enum value for a certain protobuf-serialized class in a new app version, and while testing, noticed that the previous version will throw an exception, given this new file format:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' occurred in protobuf-net.dll
Additional information: No {enum-type-name} enum is mapped to the wire-value 3
```

It is fairly obvious that it's telling me that there is no enum value for the `int` value of `3`, but I always had the idea that [Protocol Buffers defaulted to the zero-valued ("default") enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10392952/69809) (if such exists), in case that an actual enum value couldn't be mapped to.

To clarify, this can be reproduced using the following example (I am intentionally doing the deserialization step into a different class to mimic old app trying to load the new format):

```
// --- version 1 ---

public enum EnumV1
{
    Default = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassV1
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public EnumV1 Value { get; set; }
}



// --- version 2 ---

public enum EnumV2
{
    Default = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3 // <- newly added
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassV2
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public EnumV2 Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code will fail:

```
// serialize v2 using the new app
var v2 = new ClassV2() { Value = EnumV2.Three };
var v2data = Serialize(v2);

// try to deserialize this inside the old app to v1
var v1roundtrip = Deserialize<ClassV1>(v2data);
```

Since v1 is out in the open, is there some metadata I can use when serializing in v2 to avoid this issue? I can, of course, get myself out of this trouble by rewriting v2 to use a separate property and leave the enum values unmodified, but I'd like to make enums backwards compatible if possible.

Comment: What should happen to `v1roundtrip.Value` when `EnumV2.Three` was sent?

Comment: @Caramiriel: According to my understanding (explained in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10392952/69809)), it should have been set to `EnumV1.Default` instead of throwing an exception. That's what I would expect if I want to ensure that the format is backwards compatible. For example, [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13924171/69809) appears to have had the same issue, and fixed it by adding a default (zero) enum value, with no additional protobuf attributes needed.

Comment: @jgauffin: exactly what I was going to comment, seems like an easy way for Marc to get these points (I am presuming I didn't configure something right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since v1 is out in the open, is there some metadata I can use when serializing in v2 to avoid this issue? I can, of course, get myself out of this trouble by rewriting v2 to use a separate property and leave the enum values unmodified, but I'd like to make enums backwards compatible if possible.

What you are experiencing is a **protobuf-net** bug described here [protobuf-net - issue #422: Invalid behaviour while deserializing unknown enum value](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/issues/422).

It seems that it's not fixed yet according to here [protobuf-net faulty enum exception (issue 422) need a good workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236582/protobuf-net-faulty-enum-exception-issue-422-need-a-good-workaround) (and of course your post).

Unfortunately you need to either fix the `protobuf-net` source code or use the workarounds mentioned.

**UPDATE:** I've checked the code in the [GitHub](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) repository and confirming that the issue is still not fixed. Here is the problematic code inside the [EnumSerializer.cs](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Serializers/EnumSerializer.cs) (the `ISSUE #422` comment is mine):

```
public object Read(object value, ProtoReader source)
{
    Helpers.DebugAssert(value == null); // since replaces
    int wireValue = source.ReadInt32();
    if(map == null) {
        return WireToEnum(wireValue);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < map.Length ; i++) {
        if(map[i].WireValue == wireValue) {
            return map[i].TypedValue;
        }
    }
    // ISSUE #422
    source.ThrowEnumException(ExpectedType, wireValue);
    return null; // to make compiler happy
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `[ProtoContract(EnumPassthru=true)]` to your enums will allow protobuf-net to deserialize unknown values.

Unfortunately, there is no way to retroactively fix your v1. You'll have to use a different property.

Comment: But wouldn't this set the deserialized value to `3` (even if it didn't have a matching enum), instead of the default value? I still expected the default value to be used in case actual enum couldn't be resolved?

Comment: Yes.

If you need the value on the old version to be the default and the value on the new version to be some new enum value (in this case, 3), then you have to switch over to a new property every time you add a new value to your enum.

Answer (score 1):

Your ClassV1 lacks forward compatiblity.

I would have implemented the Proto contract in such a way that it serializes/deserializes the string representation of the enum value. This way you can handle the fallback to the default value by yourself. The Value property would not be serialized/deserialized.

```
public enum EnumV1
{
    Default = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

public enum EnumV2
{
    Default = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3 // <- newly added
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassV1
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string ValueAsString
    {
        get { return Value.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                Value = (EnumV1) Enum.Parse(typeof (EnumV1), value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Value = EnumV1.Default;
            }
        }
    }

    public EnumV1 Value { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassV2
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string ValueAsString
    {
        get { return Value.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                Value = (EnumV2)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumV2), value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Value = EnumV2.Default;
            }
        }
    }

    public EnumV2 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Still it does not solve the problem of having a non-forward-compabtible class in production.

Comment: There are many ways to ensure backward/forward compatibility. A simpler way (for an enum) which would work would be to de/serialize the `int` value. But this is not what I did, because I relied on protobuf to be able to handle this. I designed v1 contract believing that *Protocol Buffers defaulted to the zero-valued enum value, in case that an actual enum value couldn't be mapped to*, and I would like to see 1) why this doesn't work and 2) at least how to intercept and handle this case while deserializing. Your answer neither explains *why* `ClassV1` lacks fw compatibility, nor what to do now.

Comment: The lack of forward compatibility comes from ClassV1 not supporting new enum values, which can be considered as value types consisting compile-time-constants.
It's like implementing a switch/case statement without the default branch and let it handle unsupported cases.

Comment: I don't think that setting the default value is a responsibility of protobuf. 
I would let class ClassV1 take care of this itself by initializing the property during instanciation, instead of leaving it unitialized (boolean fields are also initialized with false implicitly).
proto-buf will throw nonthless which is fine because it shows that there is a compatibilty issue.

Comment: First, [according to documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10392952/69809), protobuf *should* be able to handle new enum values. Next, I am not talking about the default value. Obviously, the property will be initialized to a default value when I instantiate it, regardless of the attribute, and independent of serialization. As developer guide for protobuf states, *if you have a communications protocol that uses protocol buffers as its data format, you can extend your protocol without having to worry about breaking existing code*. That's one of the main selling points for protocol buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the DefaultValue attribute to your proto member property.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ClassV1
{
    [ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(EnumV1.Default)]
    public EnumV1 Value { get; set; }
}
```

To make clear how the property should be initialized for the default case.

Comment: Did you try this? I don't think this has anything to do with the exception.